# QC ALM REST API using java

Tags: java, api, rest, hp-quality-center

Can any one help me on QC ALM REST API's.
What are all the things we need to configure to work on this?
I have access to QC 10. Can i use same QC 10 url to connect using ALM REST API's

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use QC 10 url to connect using ALM Rest APIs. ALM Rest APIs are supported for HP ALM 11.0 onwards. Go to Help >> Documentation Library for more information about the ALM REST API in your ALM.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate using Help-> Documentation Library -> API References.

API examples are available in Java, .Net, VB, COM etc.

For Java use below url : replace correct your domain url.

http://qualitycenter.yourdomain.com:8080/qcbin/Help/doc_library/api_refs/REST/webframe.html